# How to solve SQL Cannot find data type BLOB during code-first migration to deploy Azure

Tags: c#, sql, azure, asp.net-core

I want to exchange the currently sqlite database that I'm using on ASP.NET Core with Azure SQL.I generated resource,sql server everything defined on project.

When I want to publish the app to deployment server of azure and sql database in cloud,it says `Cannot find data type BLOB` .I checked solutions on the internet but didn't work.I guess I have to update my model but I don't know in what way?

**Here  at first I've changed `useSqlLiteServer` to `UseSqlServer`**

```
  services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

What else should I change on my models below listed my one model below others are similiar as well

```
namespace HospitalAppointmentAPI.Models
{
    public class Patient
    {   
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string IdentityNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**DataContext.cs**

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) {}
        public DbSet<Hospital> Hospitals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    }
```

**Full Error Message during EF migrations script generation**

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5):
>   Error : Web deployment task failed. (An error occurred during
>   execution of the database script. The error occurred between the
>   following lines of the script: "23" and "39". The verbose log might
>   have more information about the error. The command started with the
>   following:
>       "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHisto"
>        Column, parameter, or variable #4: Cannot find data type BLOB. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.)
>       Failed to publish the database. This can happen if the remote database cannot run the script. Try modifying the database scripts, or
>   disabling database publishing in the Package/Publish Web properties
>   page. If the script failed due to database tables already exist, try
>   dropping existing database objects before creating new ones. For more
>   information on doing these options from Visual Studio, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179181.
>       Error details:
>       An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "23" and
>   "39". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The
>   command started with the following:
>       "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHisto"
>        Column, parameter, or variable #4: Cannot find data type BLOB. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.
>       Column, parameter, or variable #4: Cannot find data type BLOB.
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBStatementInfo.Execute(DbConnection
>   connection, DbTransaction transaction, DeploymentBaseContext
>   baseContext, Int32 timeout)
>       Publish failed to deploy.

Comment: According to the error, it may that the data type you use  in your code cannot be converted to sql server data type. For more details about sql server data type, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings? Besides, could you please provide your script?

Comment: May I know if you have tried to create and apply Initial Migration for your SQl Server database? After I updated my SQL Server database, I can successfully switch from Sqlite to SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

In Sqlite, type `BLOB` is used for storing byte array.  In SQL Server, type `byte[]` is supported.

In your case, you used Sqlite at first, then you changed to use SQL Server. So, you need to remove the migration script history.

[image]

And then create and apply Initial Migration for SQl Server database:

```
dotnet ef migrations add init -o Data\Migrations
dotnet ef database update
```

And then tables will be created in your SQL Server database. And your application will be ready to run.